# Pandas aggregate for counting with nans

Tags: numpy, pandas

The pandas count aggregate ignores nan's. I need a count that includes them. Numpy has aggregates for some but not all nan modified aggregates, do I have to use a custom aggregate or is there a way doing this that I can't find?

This is for groupby's, and I want the normal NaN functionality for mean, but weird for count. In code

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0,float('nan')],[0,float('nan')],[0,float('nan')]])

In [4]: df.groupby(0).agg(['count', 'mean'])
Out[4]:
      1
  count mean
0
0     0  NaN
```

I want the output to be 3 Nan instead of 0 NaN.

Comment: Can you show a problem that you want to solve and desired output?

Comment: Added some code, I don't know how to format it, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `len()`

```
size = lambda x: len(x)
df.groupby(0).agg(['count', 'mean', 'size'])
```

output:

```
      1          
  count mean size
0                
0     0  NaN    3
```

Comment: There's no need to define size.

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is the count, you can replace NaN values like this :

```
In [17] : df = pd.DataFrame([0,NaN,3])
          print df.count()

Out [17]: 0    2
          dtype: int64


In [18] : marker = -1
          df = df.fillna(marker)
          print df.count()

Out [18]: 0    3
          dtype: int64
```

Comment: I am trying to use multiple aggregates some of which need nan, others of which don't. This is handled for say, sum/product, but not for count.

Comment: Size is what I want.

Comment: @Snark You can use a marker like NULL or _NULL. I use the underscore to sort for groupby functions.